# How to log all resources my site needs from other sites?

Tags: logging

is there any simple way to log/list all resources my website (wordpress & theme) needs from the outside?
Like jquery, fonts and all this stuff. I want to host it on my own server. (doesn't matter if it's a good idea or not)

Comment: please just tell me on which stackexchange to post it. there are 10 million stackexchanges all talking about the same stuff. webmasters, security, serverfault .... as my concern on this matter was security i was posting it here... thanks in advance for letting me know where to post it

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox, you can install Firebug, go to the *Network* tab, and load your site. All the requests will be shown there, so you can host them on your server and change the code for your website.

Comment: Sure, that is one option. But thats only for the content which is actually displayed at the time. If i go to another part of my website maybe more/other stuff gets requested from 3rd party sites. Thats why i hope someone on security.sx can propose a more clever way. Thanks anyway :)